# FileProvider for dynamic files

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I would like to use `FileProvider` to get access of `MyFirstApplication` files in `MySecondApplication` which are stored in Internal Directory. I have gone through the documents for FileProvider and examples.

My question is, the folders and files in `InternalStorage` name may change at each instance. So in `manifest.xml` while defining the `<meta-data>` tag in `<provider>` I cannot give `xml` file with static path and name. I would like to pick the files and folders dynamically at runtime. Is this possible? If so, how can I acheive this?

**EDIT** : Here is what exactly I needed. I have two application. First application will store all files in its internal storage. Later I want to upload all those files (basically .zip files) through the second application. So those files to be accessed by second application also I need the path of those files.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Point the `<meta-data>` at the root directories in which your files and directories will exist. IOW, point at the lowest level where the locations will not change. This may require some reorganization of the rest of your code to limit the scope of your file/directory manipulation to some specific area.
2. Don't use `FileProvider`, but instead roll your own `ContentProvider` that supports the streaming API with the business rules that you wish to employ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm implementing my own `ContentProvider` to access the database of `MySecondApplication`. But how to fetch the path of a file from `ContentProvider` I googled this already and ended up with `FileProvider`. Can you please elobrate me little to get access to files or folders

Comment: @KevinChris: You don't "get access to files or folders". A `ContentProvider` works much like a Web server. You don't "get access to files or folders" with a Web server. Instead, you have URLs and you open streams on those. Same thing with a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out and accessing the `InputStream` of the file. Thanks for your valuable help.